# Science fiction book with Masonic influences and set on a starship about a war or mutiny

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book in the US, 15-20 years ago, but I believe it dated back to the 70s, based on the general feel.

It was set mostly on a starship.  I believe it and other ships had names from Freemasonry, and some of the ranks among the crew were from Masonry, such as 'Deacon' and 'Warden'.  This might have applied to the entire organization or empire that the protagonists belonged to.

I don't remember anything of the plot, except that it was conflict-based, like a war or mutiny - not a plot about exploration or discovery.

It's not *Revolt in 2100* or anything by Heinlein.  I don't believe it was by a well-known author.

Comment: The Warhammer 40K books have Deacons and Wardens. The trouble is that there are hundreds of them. Can you remember any of the ship names? Details like that are often a good way to jog memories.

Comment: @JohnRennie Good idea, but this definitely wasn't a game-related book.  I don't remember the ship names, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you suggest examples of possible ship names i.e. what sort of *names from Freemasonry* would be possible? As a non mason I have absolutely no idea what *names from Freemasonry* could mean.

Comment: I don't think they're allowed to tell us!

Comment: @JohnRennie I wish I could recall better, but I meant, something like *Square* or *Hiram* or some other term you might find on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemasonry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about [The Artifact](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0886774063) by W.Michael Gear?

Conflict based as different groups struggling to control possession of the item.  Pretty much all space based.  Main group in the story is the "Brotherhood"

Comment: Thanks!  I'm pretty sure that's it.  The cover illustration looks familiar, and the ship named *Boaz*, the Brotherhood, the character Captain Carrasco - those names sound familiar, The plot doesn't ring a bell but it's possible I didn't finish reading the book.

Comment: And according to my library software I definitely owned this book at some point.  I think I may have forgotten it at a stop during a cross-country drive around 2005, which would explain why I never finished it.